# iOS 7 navigationController navigation back error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

so when i call a button function and that push a new view in the navigation.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newviewcontroller animated:YES];
```

however, if i swipe the view back before it slide to the left. it will crash the app with the following message:

> nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
>
> Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state.
>   Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

here is my code for connecting the gesture with the delegate.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")) {self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;}
}
```

apart from simply remove the line, how can i solve that issue? is that an iOS 7 bug?

can i enable the gesture after the animation's been loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iOS 7: Interactive Pop Gesture With Custom Back Button](http://keighl.com/post/ios7-interactive-pop-gesture-custom-back-button/) - here's a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily disable it.

```
if ([systemStr floatValue] >= 7.0 && [self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: i can simply comment it out. any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you have forgot to call

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated]
```

Before dining anything in your

```
 viewDidAppear
```

Method ??